# Concatenation of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, python

1. Normal text:

   - I'm having some problems with coding on python 3.2.1. Actually I'm taking online lectures that are on python 2.5.
2. Here is the code:

   ```
   x = 100
   divisors = ()
   for i in range(1,x):
       if x%i == 0:
           divisors = divisors + (i)
   ```
3. on running the program, following error appears:

   ```
   divisors = divisors + (i)  
   TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
   ```

Comment: A list would be more appropriate for this

Comment: BTW `divisors = [i for i in range(1,x) if x % i == 0]` would give you what you want

Comment: you should have provided this as an answer. It is the best one.

Answer (score 28):

`(1)` is not a tuple,  its just a parenthesized expression.  To make it a tuple, add a trailing comma, `(1,)`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this instead:

```
divisors.append(i)
```

Edit:

```
divisors = []
```

since you can't append on tuples.

Comment: You can't use `append` on tuples.