# random.choice() from tuple with lists return undesirable item

Tags: python, loops, random

I have simple loop:

```
vegetable_list = [('potatoes', 'potatoes', 'potatoes'), ('carrot', 'carrot'), ('onion', 'onion'), ('beet')]
akg = 0

print('Random vegetable: \n')
while akg < 5:
  vegetable_random = [(i[0]) for i in vegetable_list]
  print(random.choice(vegetable_random))
  akg = akg + 1
```

But when I run it - I got normal result for items in lists, which have more than 1 item, but for `'beet'` - I got just symbol, instead of full word:

```
$ ./ovoch.py
Random vegetable:

potatoes
carrot
onion
b
b
```

So - how can I get just words from list?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6682093/3001761

Comment: See [Is this not a tuple?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15412055) and [Concatenation of tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7192391)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`('beet')` is not a tuple, it's the same as `'beet'` since tuples are created by the `,` - so you want `('beet',)`